# How to create Ceph Filesystem after Ceph Object Storage Cluster Setup?

Tags: ceph

I successfully set up a Ceph Object Storage Cluster based on this tutorial: https://www.twoptr.com/2018/05/installing-ceph-luminous.html.

Now I am stuck because I would like to add an MDS node in order to setup a Ceph Filesystem from that cluster. I have already set up the MDS node and tried to set up the FS, following several different guides and tutorials (e.g. the Ceph docs), but nothing has really worked so far.

I would be very grateful if someone could point me into the right direction of how to do this the right way. 
My setup includes 5 VM's with Ubuntu 16.04 server installed:

- ceph-1 (mon, mgr, osd.0)
- ceph-2 (osd.1)
- ceph-3 (osd.2)
- ceph-4 (radosgw, client)
- ceph-5 (mds)

I also tried to create a pool which seemed to work, because it's showing in the Ceph Dashboard, which I installed on ceph-1. But I am not sure how to continue....

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi your install not Standard 
please read a below link very helpfull for install ceph:

http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/start/quick-ceph-deploy/

then

http://docs.ceph.com/docs/mimic/cephfs/createfs/

for erasure coding below link

http://karan-mj.blogspot.com/2014/04/erasure-coding-in-ceph.html